# iBus works in Firefox, but not in gedit, libre office or terminal

Tags: 22.04, ibus, input-method

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and I installed iBus-bamboo for Vietnamese writing. I can switch to Vietnamese input method and type Vietnamese characters in firefox, but in gedit, terminal, libre office, or any system input in general, I'm unable to type in Vietnamese.

Helps are appreciated!

Edit:
Applications in which ibus works: Firefox (default from ubuntu installation), discord (installed with snap), teams-for-linux (installed with snap)

Comment: Did you try rebooting after configuring ibus for the first time?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, it's a busy period for me. Yes, I use ubuntu daily and have discovered the issue for a while. I moved on because it didn't cause me much issue. Recently when I had time, I still couldn't find a solution however, that's why I posted it here.